# How to maintain Interface and Implementation in separate files simultaneously in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have several lines of code of a written class with Interface written in `testclass.h` and implementation written in `testclass.m` in Xcode. I wish when I update an entry in `testclass.m`, its counterpart in `testclass.h` can be updated automatically.

For example, I have an interface for following function in both `testclass.h` and `testclass.m`:

`-(void)testfunction`

And I modified its name to a different one due to some reason in `testclass.m` to:

`-(void)another_test_function`

If I want this code to run I need to manually change the entry in the header. Although I'm very new to programming but I can imagine it could be really frustrating if you are trying to modify something in a big program with a lot of different files invoking some modified entry name. I wish Xcode can auto-detect this change and modify the entry in the header file to `-(void)another_test_function` automatically.

Is there any way I can do that? All I know by searching the internet is that you can use a shortcut to "edit all in scope" but this only affect all the occurrence in the same file, not header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the method name you would like to change (in either the header or the implementation file) and then select Refactor > Rename.  You can then change the name of the method, and Xcode will show you what it will change.

If that looks good, you can accept the changes and you're done.

Comment: Thanks then I know this function is actually implemented in the Xcode. Follow up question: How to add/remove some colon in the name so it can handle more/less arguments than the original one? I've tried Refactor> Rename and it doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. There's a good reason why this isn't possible, too -- if you added a colon, what would Xcode pass in for the new argument in all the places the method is called? If you want to change the method that drastically, you should probably just add a new method as you usually would.